# Flutter web copy image from clipboard

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I need to be able to paste an image that is already copied and after pasting the image it should pop up and get ready to get submitted to database. I was able to paste text from clipboard but images doesn't seem to get pasted or its location in text.

What can I try?